# The problem in running JS in jupyter notebook in vscode

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

I copy my code from the jupyter notebook to notebook in vscode(connect to the Node.js kernel)
and it has something wrong.

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
D:\Anaconda\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\node-gyp-build\index.js:60
  throw new Error('No native build was found for ' + target + '\n    loaded from: ' + dir + '\n')
  ^

Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=108 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.11.0
    loaded from: D:\Anaconda\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\zeromq

    at load.path (D:\Anaconda\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\node-gyp-build\index.js:60:9)
    at load (D:\Anaconda\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\node-gyp-build\index.js:22:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Anaconda\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\zeromq\binding.js:1:43)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Anaconda\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\zeromq\lib\index.js:6:11)

Node.js v18.11.0. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Because I'm a novice,I have no idea to solve this problem...

I have no idea for what to do next,and I just want to make this kernel useful enough for a learner.

Comment: [Error: No native build was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275743/local-native-node-module-causes-error-uncaught-error-no-native-build-was-found)
This might solve your error